# Exporting WAR from eclipse, can not find mysql driver. Fine when run from eclipse

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse, jsp, tomcat

I am new to Java and am struggling to run a piece of code on my machine. Inside of eclipse I was able to easily add the mysql-connector jar file to the WEB-INF/lib folder, and the database connection works fine when I start the tomcat server from within eclipse. However, if I export the project as a WAR file and deploy it in tomcat on my local machine, it dies as soon as I try to make a query.

It bombs out with a Null Pointer Exception, so I had a look in the log files and it looks like it can not find the driver (despite it being in WEB-INF).

I have tried copying the mysql connector, on ubuntu, into /usr/share/java, /usr/share/tomcat7/lib and /user/share/tomcat7/bin/lib to no avail.

I have tried setting the driver path manually in project settings -> data connection to no avail.

I have ready many similar questions that have been resolved with people copying the connector into WEB-INF or the tomcat/lib folder, but in my case it does nothing. I do not know enough about java to understand why it works when spawned from eclipse, but not when deployed as a war file.

Thanks so much!

Comment: export the war and look whether does it contain driver jar or not?

Comment: Indeed, it is in the WEB-INF folder of the exported WAR file.

Comment: Yes, it is 100% in there.

Comment: then it should be under `WEB-INf/lib` folder.

Comment: Yes, we have established it is in the WEB-INF/lib folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you get a ClassPath Exception and an NPE (NullPointerException). The basic cause of this exception are either the JAR file is missing or there were multiple JAR file in the library path. Lets do a basic troubleshooting:

```
   1st: Check if your MYSQL-CONNECTOR JAR file was included in the library of WAR <WEB-INF/lib>.
   2nd: Remove other MYSQL library from tomcat lib.
   3rd: While your tomcat is running, remove the WAR project from the tomcat webapps folder and wait for a few seconds until everything is clear
   4th: Restart your tomcat
   5th: Copy your WAR file into the tomcat/webapps folder.
```

The other scenario if you have only the NPE. That means you have some variable being accessed and it's null or not initialized. This happens also when you're accessing a property file and the name was misspelled.

Comment: Before I go around deleting a bunch of things: Could this be from multiple mysql-connectors in my build path like you mentioned? I added it to every single lib folder I could find that had jar files. (locate *.jar). Do I need to remove them all?

Comment: You just need to delete the mysql-connector jar file. When creating a WAR file and you want to include a JAR file, either you will put the JAR file in the WAR WEB-INF\lib folder or in the Tomcat\lib folder but not both. When you put the JAR file in Tomcat\lib while the TC is running, you need to restart it.

Comment: This had no effect. I removed them all to no avail. Finally, to make positive, I removed the webapp/WEB-INF/lib one, now it just crashes when trying to get a connection instead of when I try to make a prepared statement.

That might be an important distinction... it doesn't crash, it seemingly passes it's self a NULL connection instance without complaining, but only happens when run from a WAR file, not from within eclipse.

Comment: You may need to check the connection parameter when you initialized the `DriverManager`. StackTrace message would be helpful to understand the issue you're getting.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/Z4m4bD2p

^ From Catalina.out and localhost.log in /var/log/tomcat7



It should be noted this does not happen when launching from eclipse, which is the most perplexing part of this for me.

Comment: I'm not sure what your code looks like, but you may need check how you initialized the DriverManager and the syntax ie: `Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("<url>","<user_name>","<password>");` the JAR file `mysql-connector-java-5.0.8-bin.jar` should be in your WEB-INF\lib folder.

Comment: The `Not Suitable Driver` caused either the Library is not loaded or the URL does not match any of the loaded driver. Regarding the DriverManager, you could do it like `DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:<port>/<dbname>?user=<user>&password=<password>");` also check that you have loaded the driver from the beginning.

Comment: this.con = DriverManager.getConnection(this.conf.dburl, this.conf.dbuser, this.conf.dbpass);

This works when being run from eclipse, but silently returns NULL when run from a deployed WAR

Comment: It seems that it's not the driver. You may need to check if the `this.conf.dburl, this.conf.dbuser, this.conf.dbpass` have value when it runs from the WAR file. Try putting the actual value i.e. `this.con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:replace_actualport/replace_actualdbname?user=replace_actualuser​&password=replace_actualpassword");`

Comment: I'm pretty lost. I both hardcoded AND pumped out the values of this.conf when it fails, the values are all correct but getConnection still silently fails.

Comment: Load the driver before calling the `getConnection` i.e. `Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");`

Comment: I'm not sure if I feel like an idiot for not figuring this out or if I feel like the dev environment eclipse is providing is misleading. Adding Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"); fixed everything! It absolutely kills me to have spent so much time on this, and I have no understanding as to why it worked when launched from eclipse but not from tomcat's war/webapp?

Comment: To answer your question regarding eclipse: When you add the JAR file manually in the LIBRARIES (PROPERTIES -> JAVA BUILD PATH -> LIBRARIES) that basically initialized your Class Driver without using the code `Class.forName...`. And when you exporting it to WAR file, it doesn't include the settings you defined on YOUR LIBRARIES because that is only for your Eclipse configuration, the Eclipse will package what is defined in ORDER AND EXPORT and you need to load the Driver using the `Class.forName...`. Hope that clarifies.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to include jar files while creating your war file. Right click the project -> Properties -> Java Build Path -> Order and Export, select your JAR file.

Comment: I have done this and it has not had an effect.

It is listed under web app libraries and apache libraries, and both are exported on that tab you mention.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like Tomcat and bundled DBCP find the driver class only if the driver is placed in Tomcat's common lib folder - not in the war's WEB-INF folder.

I had this issue, where it would just not 'find' the driver as long as it is kept in my application's WEB-INF/lib.

Once I moved postgres driver jar to `eclipse-workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp3/lib` it started working just fine. (As long as the postgres driver was inside `eclipse-workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp3/wtpwebapps/MyProj/WEB-INF/lib` it was not detected.)

Here, `eclipse-workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp3/` is the tomcat root folder automatically created by defining a tomcat server runtime in eclipse.

*I assume DBCP is loaded via the Bootstrap classloader and it is not able to find the driver if it is located in the application lib folder / WAR.*